# The cannot do the update function. I think my $id assign value something wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver

This code is the function. I want to assign value from database to update.

`$row_Recordset1['Reservation_ID']` is the primary key value I want to update.

```
    function saveimage($name, $image)
          {
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("myhomestay",$con);
            echo $id=$row_Recordset1['Reservation_ID'];
            $qry="UPDATE reservation SET PaymentProof_Slip='$image' WHERE Reservation_ID='$id'";
            $result=mysql_query($qry, $con);
            if($result)
            {
              echo "<br/>Image uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "<br/>Image not uploaded.";
            }

          }
    ?>
```

This code for retrieve data from database.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_MyHomeStay_System, $MyHomeStay_System);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM reservation natural join guest natural join homestay WHERE Guest_Email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $MyHomeStay_System) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: $id value is from database. For example in my database i have Reservation_ID = 37.

Comment: are you got the $id ?

Comment: echo $id=$row_Recordset1['Reservation_ID'];

Comment: reservation_id value is in the table or database???

Comment: reservation_id is in the database where it is from reservation table

Comment: select that table and get the value of the row and store it in $id

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding ...

If you got the $id value then

Replace below coding

```
$qry="UPDATE reservation SET PaymentProof_Slip='$image' WHERE Reservation_ID='$id'";
```

to

```
$qry="UPDATE reservation SET PaymentProof_Slip='".$image."' WHERE Reservation_ID='".$id."'";
```

Comment: its still same, although it said the image is uploaded but still it does not upload in the database

Comment: i dont think so because i have assign directly value in $id. For example $id=37. Like this i able to update

Comment: Already I ask you got the $row_Recordset1['Reservation_ID']; value in that function, check it, echo  $row_Recordset1['Reservation_ID']; exit;